# Define a sympy symbol for physics value "hbar" that will print with latex

Tags: latex, sympy

Sympy has the ability to print expressions with latex.  In pure latex, the physics symbol [image] ("hbar") is simply `$\hbar$`.

`sympy.galgebra.GA` has a `make_symbols()` method that provides extended symbol naming capabilities, but I don't see a way to create "hbar".

I want to define a sympy expression which contains the symbol "hbar" which will render as the physics symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a SymPy symbol `'hbar'`. SymPy will understand it and generate the latex representation for the variable you want. I tested this on SymPy version 1.1.1. If you have an older version and this does not work, please consider updating.

```
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing()

h = sp.Symbol('hbar')
print(sp.latex(h)) # prints \hbar
```

Thus, you can check that the LaTeX representation of the variable `h` is indeed `$\hbar$`.

Comment: Thanks.

`sympy.latex(h)` does produce the proper latex expression `$\hbar$`

However, when I do `sympy.pprint(h)` what appears in my ipython session looks like `$\bar{h}$`

Perhaps that's the closest I can get.

Comment: If possible you can use [Jupyter Console](https://qtconsole.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to get all the latex goodness. But if you run IPython from a terminal emulator, I guess you can't do better than `pprint`. If you use the `init_printing()` then you don't need to `pprint`.

Comment: OK.  It renders properly in a Jupyter notebook.  I'll check out Jupyter console.  IPython from a terminal emulator is probably limited to unicode.

Comment: Yes. That&#39;s true. If you like, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the tick mark on the left.